# Server side UI vs. Client side UI

Tags: gui-design, selling-ux, client

I'm reading a job description which reads...

> You are an experienced front-end developer with expertise in
>   Javascript,HTML,CSS & server side UI frameworks (PHP/Python/Node.js).

I've always felt that it's best to render on the client side so I use AngularJS for this. Not PHP/Python/Node.js.

Is this bullet on the job description wrong? What would some valid arguments be for rending on the client instead of the server?

Comment: I think it's a poorly phrased requirement. I think they want the applicant to have knowledge of server-side frameworks that interact with UI.

Comment: Assume IT job descriptions are 50% accurate, at best.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a job listing skills requirement and not a UX issue.

Comment: I would apply can ask for $20k more than they're offering because they have zero clue as to what they need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree there is a likelihood that the job description is incorrect. However server side frameworks provide tools to build UI. E.g www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/table.html

Or

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Widgets

I guess the meaning is the developer needs to understand how to prepare data on back end to handle in on UI.